# How do I make sure a debug build and appstore build are identical?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, certificate, provisioning

I need to make sure that the same app I sent to a client for testing, can be the exact same app in the AppStore.

My workflow: from XCode I make a debug/test build for my client.
After testing, if they say "go ahead, release it in the appstore", I would like to upload a binary thats the closest match to the build they just approved. Ideally, it should be identical.

I can solve this in several ways:

1) I use my companys usual distribution profile to make a debug/test build. This requires the client to inform me of every device they might consider installing the test app on. More often than not, they keep adding more and more devices as time goes by, making extra work for me updating the provisioning profile multiple times. Not ideal. The upside is, I can upload the exact same archive to the appstore, using the appstore provisioning profile instead.

2) I use an enterprise profile for making the debug/test app. The upside doing it this way, is the client can install it on as many devices as they need to. No registering of UUIDS is required. The downside: I need to make a new archive, as you cant use the enterprise profile for the appstore. This leaves room for error - and the posibility that the app on the appstore is not exactly as intended.

3) I might ask my client upfront, to supply me all their certificates/profiles etc making me able to build all apps, for testing and the appstore, with their certificate/profiles. This way, its likely their devices are already added to the provisioning profiles, and when the time comes to submit to the appstore, I don't need to make a new archive. I just make a binary from the archive, with their appstore provisioning profile instead.

In short, this is ideally what I need:
I make a debug/test build, upload it to TestFlight. My client installs it on as many devices as they need to.
If they dont find any bugs and gives me the go-ahead, I want to be able to upload the exact same build to the appstore. This way, I am sure its the same app they tested/approved, that actually goes in the appstore.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use option 1 or 3.  In my work, we have a handful of on-site testers who get a true debug build straight from Xcode.  Then we have a few off-site testers.  For these offsite testers, I generate an `.ipa` file and send it to them.  If the current version of the app is deemed app-store ready, the `.ipa` I upload to the app store is the exact same one I sent to the off-site testers.

---

Note that this is actually a release build.  It will perform identically to an app on the appstore.  Depending on how you write you code, you may notice no difference.  But for me, I wrap all of my `NSLog` statements in `#if DEBUG`, as well as a few other things.  In the `.ipa` file build you distribute for testing, Xcode will define `DEBUG` as `0`, so this code won't execute (and `NSLog` statements generally shouldn't be executing in release builds anyway).